# Lou Diamond Phillips' first movie?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I realize IMDb shows Lou Diamond Phillips' first movie as *Time Bomb* (1984), but I distinctly remember watching a Christian movie at church as a young teen (early 80's), with him in it. Then when *La Bamba* came out, I was like: "Hey, that's the same guy!"

I grew up in a super conservative church in which secular movies were not allowed; so being able to watch a movie/video at church was a big deal, even though it was a Christian-based movie. I think this may have been the first "movie" I had ever seen besides TV. I don't remember anything about the movie except that it took place in western US during modern times (think old-gas-station-in-dusty-west type of movie).

Did he get his start in Christian movies, or am I going nuts? It was a long time ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are absolutely right. LDP's first role was in a Christian youth film in the early 80s where he played a boxer, and it's not on IMDb. Says LDP in an [interview](http://www.avclub.com/article/ilongmireis-lou-diamond-phillips-on-ila-bambai-the-83059):

> My very first film ever was a little thing called **Angel Alley**, which was a Christian youth film that was made by the Kuntz brothers and was directed by a guy who became a very, very dear friend of mine, Fred Holmes.

It was about an hour long. You can read about it in [this online synopsis](http://www.christianfilmdatabase.com/review/angel-alley/) of the VHS:

> Angel Alley realistically portrays a teenager’s struggle to get in tune with God’s plan for his life. Nick was praying for guidance. Would there be a handwriting on the wall... or a voice from Heaven? Nick knew the Lord had a plan for his life... but he didn’t know how to find it.

You can see some pics from the film [here](http://www.loudiamondphillips.co.uk/angelalleygall.html).

Comment: Oh wow, that's it! So quick too. Does IMDB not include Christian-based movies, or is this an oversight?

Comment: This might have been some sort of locally circulated VHS. IMDb doesn't document some of them.

Comment: @Walt that website is hilariously 90's